# buttons disappear after pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning javascript, and I am practicing what I learned by making a blackjack game. I have a system that deals cards fairly, but when I press the "deal" button the value of the card comes up but the buttons disappear. Why is this happening? Any help will be much appreciated. here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>casino game.</title>
<input type="button" value="deal" onclick="document.write(random)" id="deal">
<input type="button" value="hit" onclick="hit" id="hit">
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var deck =     [11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10];
var random = deck[Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length)]

</script>
<style type="text/css">
#deal{
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 100px;

}
#hit{
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 200px;
}

body{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: url("");
}

</style>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have completely confused the meaning of `<head>` and `<body>`… anyway, don’t use `document.write` and don’t use inline event handlers such as `onclick=""`. Also `hit` isn’t a complete statement and results in a reference error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `<input>` inside `<body>` instead of `<head>`, and by using `document.write()` you are overwriting all the content of your HTML. You might want to write the result in a `<div>` instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>casino game.</title>
<style type="text/css">
#deal{
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 100px;

}
#hit{
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 200px;
}

body{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: url("");
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="deal" onclick="deal()" id="deal">
<div id="result"></div>

<input type="button" value="hit" onclick="hit" id="hit">

<script type="text/javascript">
var deck = [11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10];

function deal() {
    var random = deck[Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length)];     
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = random;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pusiyaciwe/edit?html,js,console,output)</kbd>